# Is the Timefold documentation in PDF format still available? Or where has it been moved to?

Tags: timefold

All,

Timefold continues to develop the Optaplanner framework. However, despite looking through the timefold site (and its documentation), I fail to find the updated documentation in PDF format. Has that PDF documentation been discontinued (which would be really disappointing, TBH) ? Sorry if I'm just looking in the wrong places, but I just can't seem to find it...

Answer (score 2):

It is produced during the build process, but it is not published anywhere.
[Timefold Solver Documentation](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/introduction/introduction) is now online, but if you need the PDF, you can build it in this module:

```
https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/tree/main/docs
```

Using [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), call:

```
mvn clean install -Dfull
```

And find the generated PDF in `target/generated-docs/pdf/`.

Comment: That's the way StackOverflow operates - people who only know a little about the topic, if anything at all, consider the question too short or poorly described. Some don't like the lack of code. And so the question gets downvoted. Our own Github Discussions don't judge. :-) https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/discussions